# Rendering huge, interactive SVGs in a browser

Tags: javascript, svg, web, buffer, autocad

We have to display huge SVG documents (about 20mb) inside a web application. Users should be able to zoom in and move the image.

Rendering the SVG directly as a DOM object is too slow and the performance is inconsistent. The same applies for painting it on a canvas.

Generally, handling SVG on the client side seems weak. So I thought of implementing a server-side solution for providing the data in small chunks, in a non-vector format. If the user is not interacting with the document, the buffer starts lazy loading higher detailed pieces. My concern with this solution is, that the network traffic could be critical.

We will be rendering 2D DWG / DXF files, which will be converted to SVG.

The AutoCAD API seems really slow. The DWG sample does not work on any of our devices. Also, the application has to run without an internet connection, so we can't use the AutoCAD REST API.

How would you solve this? Are browsers even built for handling huge vector graphics?

Answer (score 2):

When it comes to SVG it depends on the number of nodes, gradients, opacity and blur effects; however, why not use the end-user's graphics accelerator to handle this?

Most modern web browsers are made to support graphics acceleration through WebGL -with which you can build very complex (and "huge") rich graphics in 2D (or 3D) that is handled as fast as your graphics accelerator can handle it; exactly like modern games.

Using a WebGL library is recommended where a lot of work has been done for you already:

- **PlayCanvas** : https://playcanvas.com/  -- you can import other formats, build & script your scenes with a friendly interface. PlayCanvas is well documented.
- **Three.js** : http://threejs.org/ -- an advanced WebGL library, aimed at coders. ThreeJS can also handle many different types of 3D formats and this library is also well documented.

With Three.js you can also render your graphics as SVG, however, using WebGL is recommended for the obvious advantages in speed and quality.

Both of these libraries are very powerful, have an active community and is well supported in modern web browsers; however there are many others you can try.

For more information on the libraries mentioned above, it's best to visit the sites where extensive information and examples are available.

Answer (score 1):

Instead implementing yourself, I would suggest you use the [Autodesk Viewer](https://360.autodesk.com/viewer), also available for developers with full [REST + JavaScript APIs](http://developer.autodesk.com/api/viewerapi/).

Basically this library will convert your DWG file (2D or 3D) into a JSON stream and adjust the amount of data according to the browser/device capabilities. It uses [Three.js](http://threejs.org/), but you don't need to handle the geometry directly (but you can).

Check the [Forge](http://forge.autodesk.com) [Github](https://github.com/Developer-Autodesk) for samples. I like the [Galley](http://viewer.autodesk.io/node/gallery/#/home) better.

You may also run it locally using NodeJS to server it to the browser. The [Extract sample](http://extract.autodesk.io) does the whole process.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Augusto. The 2D samples don't seem to work at all. We need a reliable solution. The performance is really bad. Maybe in a few years, this API will be a good solution.

Comment: @ChristophBühler, if you have a sample that is not working, I'm very interested in knowing why... if possible, please share (either original or viewer link)

Comment: I really appreciate your work! The Forge Platform is huge. It's just generally really slow on older machines (I bet it would run great on my private computer). All we need is an interactive 2D visualisation that runs without an internet connection. Is this possible with the AutoCAD SDK? I wanted to send a link, but Chrome died in the process of loading the viewer. Can you send a working 2D example? Maybe, I just click the wrong links.

Comment: I have edited my answer with extract sample, it can run offline or inside your local server. There are some ActiveX plugins for IE, but we're not recommending it anymore (legacy technology)